# Teradata FastLoad Inmod Compilation on Windows or Unix

Tags: windows, unix, gcc, compilation, teradata

I have an inmod for processing one file records and eliminate some unwanted rows and then feed the records to fastload utility. But I am not able to find a correct way to compile it and use it. I have GCC (GNU C Compiler) and TCC (Tiny C Compiler) on my windows macine and I got Fastload utility also installed. I tried to compile the code into a DLL and I succeded in that using below commands.

gcc -c mydll.c
gcc -shared -o mydll.dll mydll.o

But I don't know whats next....

Do I have to compile it in a separate way and Do I need to link it to fastload somewhere?

I also have a unix machine installed with Fastload and GCC. So if you have ever done inmod setup on unix please share the same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling an inmod is nothing but compiling a c code into dll (for windows ) or shared object (.so for unxi). Please find the commands to be used below.

windows

```
gcc -c mydll.c
gcc -shared -o mydll.dll mydll.o
```

unix

```
gcc -c myso.c
gcc -G -Bdynamic -o myso.so myso.o
```